# Show both Tab bar and Toolbar in Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm a beginner in mobile app development and I'm developing an android app using Xamarin forms for a project.

it has 3 tabbed pages.

each page needs some actions to be done when a user clicks on something.

since there are few actions in one tab to be clicked and actions are different for each tab, I want to show both toolbar and tab bar at the same time just like "Whatsapp" shows in there interface.

I have 3 pages named Farm, Treatments, and Autopsy.

all 3 pages are showing as tabbed pages in the tabbedPageContainer XAML.

this is the tabbedPageContainer XAML Code

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TabbedForms.TabbedPages.TabbedPageContainer"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:TabbedForms.TabbedPages" 
            >

    <pages:page_Farm />
    <pages:Page_Treatments/>
    <pages:Page_Autopsy/>

</TabbedPage>
```

and this TabbedPageContainer is my Main page.

What I have so far is something like this 
[image: My Design]

but what I want is something like this 
[image: Whatsapp design]

how can I achieve this in Xamarin forms XAML?

This is the App.XAML

```
using System;
using TabbedForms.TabbedPages;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TabbedForms
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new TabbedPageContainer();
            //Background color
            //MainPage.SetValue(NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty, Color.Black);
            //Title color
            // MainPage.SetValue(NavigationPage.BarTextColorProperty, Color.White);
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm using VS 2019 Enterprise edition and testing on android 8.1**

Comment: Can you show me your `MainActivity` and `App.xaml.cs`?

Comment: @FreakyAli 
TabbedPageContainer is the main page. Other pages are displayed in these tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.Xaml:

```
 public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage( new TabbedPage1());
        }
```

Tab page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:page="clr-namespace:XamarinControls"
             x:Class="XamarinControls.TabbedPage1">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
  <page:Page4 Title="Tab 1" />
  <ContentPage Title="Tab 2" />
  <ContentPage Title="Tab 3" />
</TabbedPage>
```

Content Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             x:Class="XamarinControls.Page4">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Priority="0"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Noti" Priority="1"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

It worked for me.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: @ Bharath 
I tried this but it doesn't work. actually it does nothing.

Comment: it gives me this error:
 
cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.Tab' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'

Comment: tabbedPageContainer is inherited from TabbedPage and I think that might be the reason I'm getting this error.

Comment: @KLM I edited the answer please check that solution is worked for me

Comment: I just changed that "new TabbedPage1" to my "tabbedPageContainer" in app.xaml.cs and it really worked.
Thank you so much for your kind help @Bharath.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the child ContentPage of the Tabbed in a NavigationPage like

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <NavigationPage Title="xxx" IconImageSource="xxx">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:ItemsPage1 />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="xxx" IconImageSource="xxx">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:ItemsPage2 />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```